# Any fix for Portal 2 hang/freeze on PS3?

Tags: ps3, technical-issues, portal-2

I checked out a copy of *Portal 2* from the library, hoping to spend part of Father's Day gaming. Whenever I put the weighted cube on the switch in test chamber 6, my PS3 freezes. I've cleaned my disc off. My Google-fu is weak and I wasn't able to find any info about this kind of an issue. Four or five updates downloaded and installed before I started playing.

*Is this a known issue?* How do I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The disc was bad. I got a different copy from my library and was able to play past the freeze. There was a brief one second pause after I went through the room's exit door, but the game came right back.